# Convert SHA-1 string to plain text java

Tags: java, hash, sha1, sha

I tried to search this but surprisingly could not find any results of converting SHA-1 generated string back to normal string. I hash a string to SHA-1 and then send it to some other device where this SHA-1 generated string should be unhashed and used but I am unable to find any such method in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and other [hashing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is that **there is no such thing as unhashing**. There is no such method in Java or any other language.

What you are searching for is [symmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing hashing with encryption (this is what you would probably want to use instead). Encryption is reversible given a key, while hashing is not.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are one way, you can go from text to hash but not the other way.
Have a look at this for a nice discussion:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t